# Settings disabled in flash context menu

Tags: flash

I have two flash movies, both *seem* to have the same embed/object params and publish settings, but one will display the 'settings' option and one won't.
I would really like the user to be able to select the settings, but can't figure out how to force it to be enabled, or even find any information on under which circumstances it would be disabled.
Google just wants to tell me about custom context menus, which is not quite the point.
Anyone got any clues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Argh. It was the stage size of the flash movie - too small to display the settings dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Guess, minimal dimensions to enable settings menu item provided in [this discussion](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/898260) will be helpful to anyone:

> It appears that there is a minimum width and height requirement for
>   the settings dialog to be enabled.
>
> Try setting your swf width >= `215px` and height >= `138px`.